# Error when trying to run default C# HSPI A template

Tags: hspi

I downloaded Visual Studio 2017 Community and installed it on my Windows 10 PC.  I downloaded the HomeSeer templates from the VS "marketplace" and installed them.  I created a new project from the C# HSPI "A" template and pressed F5 to start the debug; I get 1 error message:

```
Error       The command "powershell -file c:\users\paul\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\HSPIPluginA1\HSPIPluginA1\fix-output.ps1 -configuration Debug -executionpolicy Unrestricted -NonInteractive" exited with code -196608.

Project: HSPIPluginA1   File: c:\users\paul\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\HSPIPluginA1\HSPIPluginA1\HSPIPluginA1.csproj    Line: 77
```

Do you have any idea what I did wrong?  I'm pretty bad if I can't even get the default, pre-packaged, code to work.

Also, how do I provide an alternate IP Address for the plugin to connect to?  My HS3 runs on a remote Linux (Lubuntu 16.04 LTS) machine.  Thanks in advance.

I did not mean to imply that I was frustrated with you - it was me I was frustrated with; there just seems to be so much to learn.  I know how much time and effort it takes to create/package/edit/document things so other folks can use them, so I certainly don't want to be a "whiner" right at the start.  I also really appreciate you made the modifications to the template so quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

1. I just published an update to the extension that corrects the problem you were having. The corresponding tracking issue is https://github.com/alexdresko/HSPI/issues/62
2. I haven't finished the documentation yet, but you can see how to change the IP and port by going to https://github.com/alexdresko/HSPI/issues/7#issuecomment-283101463
3. Please do not expect perfection from this project. It's something I'm working on in my spare time and I am in no way affiliated with HomeSeer.
4. Now that I think about it, I do not know if this project will work with Linux, as that is something I haven't tested yet. I am very interested to know if it works, so please keep me updated.

Thanks again!